# How to compute correlation for each subjets using mutate?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a simple problem with my data frame. For each subject, I have a unique id, the level of a stock index, and how many of his endowment each subject has invested for this period.

| id | index | invest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 102 | 42 |
| 1 | 104 | 13 |
| 1 | ... | 72 |
| 1 | 124 | 18 |
| 2 | 102 | 52 |
| 2 | ... | 42 |
| 2 | 124 | 18 |
| 3 | 102 | 25 |

I would like to create a new column, "corr" to compute for each subject the correlation between the stock index and his investment. The corr column should contain for each row the correlation for all periods between index and invest for each subject. Therefore, each subject has only one corr value, repeated at each row.

| id | index | invest | corr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 102 | 42 | cor1 |
| 1 | 104 | 13 | cor1 |
| 1 | ... | 72 | cor1 |
| 1 | 124 | 18 | cor1 |
| 2 | 102 | 52 | cor2 |
| 2 | ... | 42 | cor2 |
| 2 | 124 | 18 | cor2 |
| 3 | 102 | 25 | cor3 |

How can I do this using mutate ?

```
#does not work
df = df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(corr = cor(index, invest))
```

More broadly, is there a functional way to apply a function "vertically" inside mutate, instead of only applying it on the row considered?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: My column are ofc numerical variable, this a just an overview of the dataframe! My problem is how to write the code (without doing loops), not about the type of my data. I will edit my post so it will be less confusing, thanks for your comment.

Comment: When you say it does not work, what exactly is going wrong? Are you getting an error or is it not giving the output that you want?

Comment: I think you are looking for `summarise` instead of `mutate`

Comment: Yeah I could do the same with summarise, but I wondering if their is a wat to do it with mutate! 

If tried with a custom function:

``` 
get_corr_by_id = function(data, id){
    corr = cor(filter(data, id == id)$invest,
               filter(data, u_id == id)$index)
    return(corr)
} 
data = mutate(data, corr = get_corr_by_id(id))
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal of `mutate()` is to modify or compute new columns based on e.g. the values of other columns and do the computation *row-wise*, It's not intended to do computations over the columns as you want here.

What you can do to achieve the desired result is to use `group_by()` to split the analysis by groups, `summarize()` to compute the correlation among the columns of interest, and `inner_join()` to merge back the resulting correlation to the original dataset. All functions are from the `dplyr` package.

The following code illustrates the process on the `CO2` dataset that is included in base R: the correlation between columns `conc` and `uptake` is computed by each value of `Plant`.

```
library(dplyr)

# Analysis data
data(CO2)
df = CO2

# 1) Define the analysis groups
df_grp = group_by(df, Plant)

# 2) Compute correlation by groups
corr = df_grp %>% summarize(corr = cor(conc, uptake))

# 3) Merge back correlation into original dataset
df = inner_join(df, corr)  # Joins the datasets by the common column (Plant)
                           # as indicated by the displayed message.

# Check the result
df
```

The partial output looks like this:

```
   Plant        Type  Treatment conc uptake      corr
1    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0 0.7144826
2    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  175   30.4 0.7144826
3    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  250   34.8 0.7144826
4    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  350   37.2 0.7144826
5    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  500   35.3 0.7144826
6    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  675   39.2 0.7144826
7    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled 1000   39.7 0.7144826
8    Qn2      Quebec nonchilled   95   13.6 0.7372594
9    Qn2      Quebec nonchilled  175   27.3 0.7372594
10   Qn2      Quebec nonchilled  250   37.1 0.7372594
11   Qn2      Quebec nonchilled  350   41.8 0.7372594
12   Qn2      Quebec nonchilled  500   40.6 0.7372594
13   Qn2      Quebec nonchilled  675   41.4 0.7372594
14   Qn2      Quebec nonchilled 1000   44.3 0.7372594
```